# Update a specific row on SQLite for Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to update a specific row that uses auto_increment as a primary key. Basically, I initialize the table in one activity and I want to complete the table on another. So, I use the update feature to do it. However, when I log to see how many rows where affected I get 0 back. 
Here is my code:

```
public void updateValue(String updatedValue){
String strFilter = " (" + primaryKey + "== "+ "(SELECT last_insert_rowid())" + ")";
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(val, updatedValue);
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    int rows= db.update(myTable, values, strFilter, null);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "The change has affected " + rows
            + " rows.");
    db.close();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem in the following line:

```
String strFilter = " (" + primaryKey + "== "+ "(SELECT last_insert_rowid())" + ")";
```

It should be written, I guess, in the following way:

```
String strFilter = primaryKey + "=" + "(SELECT last_insert_rowid())";
```

But you should control the return of this part `(SELECT last_insert_rowid())` if it returns last inserted row or not.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
"String query = SELECT seq from SQLITE_SEQUENCE WHERE name = \'"+tableName+"\'";
```

instead of

```
SELECT last_insert_rowid()
```

Comment: what is seq? do u mean to use the name of my primary key?

Comment: seq is a special field in sqlite_sequence table which holds the value of autoincrement. You just need to indicate the table that you are looking for the autoincrement value.